# Node localhost not returning date

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have the following index.js file:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use('/',(req,res) => {

console.log(req.get('Date'));
console.log(req.get('User-Agent'));
console.log(req.url);

var name = req.query.name;
res.status(200).type('html');

res.write('Hello World! <br>');
if (name) {
   res.write('Hi, ' + name + " it's nice to see you.");
}else{
   res.write('Welcome, guest!');
}

res.end();
});

app.listen(3001, () => {
console.log('Listening on port 3001');

});
```

Why is date undefined?

Comment: Did you pass the Date header?
Above req.get('Date') is for get the data from the header.
if you use the query parameter to pass Date like "url?Date=**", then req.query.Date is correct way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because the browser you are using is not sending the date in the headers...

you could use local server date....